# Function A calls function B that calls function A, what do you call that?

Tags: c++, c

I know that when function calls themselft, it's called recursion. But how do you call when function A calls function B that calls A until there is an IF statement that stops whole proces. Look at this exercise from one C book(and by the way could I solved this better?)

> Write a function that displays a menu of four numbered choices and
>   asks you to choose one. (The output should look like the preceding.)
>
> Write a function that has two int arguments: a lower limit and an
>   upper limit. The function should read an integer from input. If the
>   integer is outside the limits, the function should print a menu again
>   (using the function from part "a" of this question) to reprompt the
>   user and then get a new value. When an integer in the proper limits is
>   entered, the function should return that value to the calling
>   function.
>
> Write a minimal program using the functions from parts "a" and "b" of
>   this question. By minimal, we mean it need not actually perform the
>   actions promised by the menu; it should just show the choices and get
>   a valid response.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Display(void);
int Limits(int a, int b);

int main(void)
{
    Display();
    return 0;
}
void Display()
{
    int y = 0;
    printf("1 - 2 - 3 - 4\n");
    y = Limits(0, 100);
    if(y < 100 && y > 0)
        printf("%d\n", y);
}
int Limits(int a, int b)
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if(x < a || x > b)
        Display();
    return x;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4
1234
1 - 2 - 3 - 4
34456
1 - 2 - 3 - 4
123
1 - 2 - 3 - 4
-34
1 - 2 - 3 - 4
-23
1 - 2 - 3 - 4
88
88
Press [Enter] to close the terminal ...
```

Comment: It's called [mutual recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion).

Comment: @user315052 Also, in the general case of > 2 functions, [*indirect recursion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Direct_and_indirect_recursion).

Comment: Glad I know proper terms because English is not my first language, so it is hard to google it(function A calls B that calls A...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called mutual recursion or (less often) cross recursion.

As far as how to solve it cleanly, it sounds to me like it fits roughly with a pattern like:

```
namespace {
    int show_menu() { 
        printf("1 - 2 - 3 - 4");
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        return n;
    }
}

int menu() { 
    int value;
    do { 
        value = show_menu();
    } while (value <1 || value > 4);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Unless there's obvious problems, there's nothing to "solve". It's the same as with "normal" recursion, you just need a termination condition.

Comment: Much better then my code, my code was ugly so I asked here for revision

Comment: @TC1: At least IMO, there are two possible problems to solve. First, that repeated incorrect inputs could simply crash the program. Second, that most people reading the code would need a fair amount of extra study to be entire certain what it did, and that what it did was what it was supposed to do.